# How to autofit Kendo TreeList column onExpand & onCollapse?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-treelist

I have a Kendo TreeList. The collapse event is bound to an `onCollapse()` method, the expand event is bound to an `onExpand()` method.

In words: the first column consists of levels. The default level is 0 and is expanded as default and shows (all of it's children) all rows of level 1. When expanding a level 1 row, its children (level 2) are shown. At the same time, the column has to stretch a bit (to show the next level number). When expanding another level 1 row, the column does not need to stretch but when a row of level 2 is expanded, the first column has to stretch again for showing level 3 and so on.

Therefore, I use `treeList.autoFitColumn(0)`. This causes an auto fit after every second expand whenever I expand rows of same level (that is not what I expect because expanding same level means the column did grow after the first expand but not after the second expand.

An alternative could be changing the width manually, but I cannot find something like `treeList.columns[0].setWidth(x)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing is happening because the `collapse` and `expand` events are firing before the width of the content has actually changed.

What you can do to circumvent this is to "delay" the auto-fit until after the current code finished running. You do this by using `setTimeout` with a 0 timeout. This places the execution of the function inside the `setTimeout` at the end of the execution queue.

See the snippet for a demo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.911/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.911/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.911/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.911/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.911/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<div id="treeList"></div>
<script>
  $("#treeList").kendoTreeList({
    resizable: true,
    columns: [
      { field: "Name" },
      { field: "Text" }
    ],
    dataSource: [
      { id: 1, Name: "Name 1", Text: "Sample text 1", parentId: null },
      { id: 2, Name: "Name 2", Text: "Sample text 2", parentId: null },
      { id: 3, Name: "Name 3", Text: "Sample text 3", parentId: 1 },
      { id: 4, Name: "Very long name 4", Text: "Sample text 4", parentId: 2 }
    ],
    expand: function(e) {
      setTimeout(() => treeList.autoFitColumn(0), 0);
    },
    collapse: function(e) {
      setTimeout(() => treeList.autoFitColumn(0), 0);
    }
  });
  var treeList = $("#treeList").data("kendoTreeList");
  treeList.autoFitColumn(0);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```